# Modified MergeSort runtime

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Help me to understand the runtime of the Modified MergeSort algorithm.
In the classic MergeSort, when the input array is divided into two parts and sorted recursively, the execution time is: nlogn

What will be the execution time of the MergeSort algorithm if
divide the input array into three parts (not half), recursively sort every third and finally merge the results using the three-argument Merge merge sub-program.

1. n
2. nlogn
3. n (log n) ^ 2
4. n ^ 2logn

Comment: In your sort, how many comparisons does it take to pick the smallest from 3 items?

Comment: @DavidZimmerman - the increase in compares is offset by a decrease in moves.

Comment: I correctly understand that when the input data is divided into three parts, the number of comparisons increases, but the number (depth) of recursion decreases. Those. the number of comparisons is balanced by the amount (depth) of recursion. As a result, the complexity of the algorithm remains the same regardless of how many parts we break up the input data.

Comment: It's still O(n log n). Only the base of the logarithm changes. So instead of `n * log_base_2(n)`, you get `n * log_base_3(n)`. You're doing fewer iterations, but there's more work per iteration.

Comment: Note that your statement, "the execution time is: nlogn" is not correct. The algorithm's complexity is O(n log n), and the execution time, is expected to be *proportional to* n log n.

Comment: @JimMischel: for example instead of `n.log2(n)` comparisons, you get `2n.log3(n)`. indeed twice as much work per iteration and fewer but more than half as many iterations, but yes, constants are meaningless and you get **O(n.log(n))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the classic Merge Sort algorithm, there are approximately `n * log2(n)` comparisons and as many element copy operations, hence the time complexity of **O(n.log(n))** because multiplicative constants are implicit.

If instead of splitting the array into 2 parts, you split into 3 parts, perform the same sort recursively on the parts and merge the 3 sorted slices into one, the number of comparisons increases to approximately `2 * n * log3(n)` and the number of element copies is reduced to `n * log3(n)`, but both are still proportional to `n * log(n)`. Factoring out multiplicative constants, you still get a time complexity of **O(n.log(n))**.